# How can I control playback in IINA using a game controller?

Tags: keyboard, video, keybindings

I want to use my game controller to fast-forward/rewind video playing in the app [IINA](https://iina.io). Specifically, I want to rotate one of the controller's joysticks counterclockwise to move IINA's playback back, and rotate the joystick clockwise to move the playback ahead.

IINA has the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>,</kbd> to go backwards one frame, and <kbd>.</kbd> to go forward one frame. I've found plenty of apps that allow me to remap gamepad buttons to keyboard keys, but none that do joystick rotation.

Is there a macOS app that will allow me to map *joystick rotation* to a keyboard button?

- Controller: SteelSeries Nimbus
- Mac: 2014 MacBook Pro
- OS: macOS Big Sur (11.6.8)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old question but maybe I have a solution for you.

If you are using Logitech joysticks, there is a seting D and X below. X is for xinput and D is direct for older games. I think Xinput is mapped in the system so you can capture the "key" strokes and remap them.

To remap the keys you want to use Karabiner Elements (you can find it at: https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). It is a great app which I used mainly for keyboard remapping. I think you will be able to do what you want with it. Just remap some of the keys to , and .

In Windows I think you can use the Logitech supplied app to do what you want, buy you can use PowerToys that have a Keyboard Manager with remap function. The other method is Sharp Keys. I use this to remap keys when I start Windows and it works great.